# How can I do Sigma (Summation)/Pi (Product) notation (or the equivalent of it) in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I want to use a Google spreadsheet to perform a calculation equating to an equation in summation notation, for example...the sum, where x goes from the number in cell A1 to the number in cell A2, is x^3 + 2. So if A1 was 2, and A2 was 7, then this formula in A3 would evaluate as:

(2^3 + 2) + (3^3 + 2) + (4^3 + 2) + (5^3 + 2) + (6^3 + 2) + (7^3 + 2)

How can I do this? I would also like to know how to do this with product notation...which is pretty much the same thing, except you multiply the terms instead of adding them.

Preferably, I'd like to do this with just three (or maybe just one or two more) cells instead of having a whole table for it...because I'd like the user to be able to enter any two whole numbers--there is no upper limit for the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

A3 would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ArrayFormula(row(OFFSET(B3,,,A2-A1+1))-row(B3)+A1)^3 + 2)
```

**Edit**

This formula is simpler:

`=SUM(ArrayFormula((row(OFFSET(B3,,,A2-A1+1))-row(B3)+A1)^3 + 2))`

only work for A1 > 0, A2 > 0, A2 > A1

**Explanaton**

[image]

`row(OFFSET(B3,,,A2-A1+1))-row(B3)+A1)` is to get numbers from 2(A1) to 7(A2):

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

`^3 + 2` is to repeat the formula: `(2^3 + 2) + ...`

The result of calculations looks like this:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula((row(OFFSET(B3,,,A2-A1+1))-row(B3)+A1)^3 + 2))
                  ( 2      3      4      5      6     7)^3 + 2
```

Comment: Max, could you explain this answer?

Comment: @RobStone, I've found shorter formula: `=SUM(ArrayFormula((row(OFFSET(B3,,,A2-A1+1))-row(B3)+A1)^3 + 2))`

Comment: What is the B3 cell for?

Comment: @Nick, your question made me rethink it again. I've added a screenshot to make the answer more clear. `B3` is just for extracting row number for creating a counter. I think I've used column `B` because the formula was in `A` and I was afraid to get a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

a shorter version:

=sum(arrayformula(row(indirect(A1&":"&A2))^3+2))

A1>0 , A2>0

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a new answer to an old question. Try to write a complete answer. Is this a short version compared to which answer? It is clear now but it might not be in the future. It is not clear on which cell you should input your answer. It is not clear what A1>0 and A2>0 are, unless people read other answers first. Also check how you can improve your post using a better formatting for formulas and code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A shorter answer to the original question:

If cells A1 and A2 are your input, then your output is the following formula in cell A3:

```
=sum(arrayformula(row(indirect(A1&":"&A2))^3+2))
```

Requirements: A1>0 , A2>0 , and both are integers

For the product:

```
=product(arrayformula(row(indirect(A1&":"&A2))^3+2))
```

HTH